# How to specify CSS style to a string without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to specify font colors for 'if', 'else', 'for' etc in html files when displayed on a browser. Is it possible to do so?
Eg:
for tags we use,

```
    h1{
    color: red;
    }
```

similarly how to specific for specific strings without using tags and class around those strings(Eg:

```
<p><span class="string">if</span>(x==10))
```

Is it possible without using jquery?

I tried

```
    "if","else"{
    color: blue;
    }
```

if I display a code, on browser, the keywords should have some colors as in the IDEs.

Comment: you cannot do this with only CSS

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript you will have to manually wrap every word with a tag and give it an id or class that can be colored in CSS. Javascript can be written to automate this, you don't need JQuery.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? You seem to be combining CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Styles are associated with DOM elements, not individual strings. If you want to give a style to a word, it has to be in its own element. If it's not in its own span in the original HTML, you'll need to write JavaScript that puts a span around it, then you can add a style to that span.

Comment: Like @Barmar said you don't need jQuery, but you will need to use Javascript and you will need to wrap each word in a tag of some sorts.